# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCcPSKlYtpdzBoAC8soeSmIARMzVKzrf5I",
  storageBucket: "challenge-4b2b2.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "962418448875",
  appId: "1:962418448875:web:f6cce5eeaf819481f661ae",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, I am sure the community needs more information/description than this. But I am just going to go out on a limb and say check your package.json file and make sure you do `npm i firebase` in root directory of project to install firebase.

Comment: i already did installation of firebase and firebase@tools